# Runing a Jetty Demo with Ant BuildException error

Tags: java, maven, ant

I build the repo over here: https://github.com/dotku/java-demo-jetty-war

I was trying to run the demo from http://woxiangbo.iteye.com/blog/1927453, but I was failed by due to the error following.

`mvn clean install`

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (main-class-placement) on project pdfcompare: An Ant BuildException has occured: C:\www\dotku.github.io\tech\java-maven\demo-war-running\target\classes does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Maven project structure isn't correct, and so your source code `CompareLuncher.java` can't be found and compiled.  Since your class isn't compiled, the `maven-antrun-plugin` is failing.

You need to update the directory structure for your sources as follows:

```
java-demo-jetty-war
  src
    main
      java
        CompareLuncher.java
```

Comment: Cool! It works, well, there is another error with: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project pdfcompare; what is this about?